# MSSQL - Invalid column name with Java/JTDS and Join

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, jtds

I want to execute the following statement using Java with JTDS in MSSQL 2005. I need it that way, because I want to show the results from position 1-15, 16-30 etc.

```
SELECT TOP 15 WID,AID,de FROM 
(SELECT WID,AID, de, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WID ASC) AS r_n_n 
FROM [database].[dbo].[table1], [database].[dbo].[table2] 
WHERE AID=Indicator) x WHERE r_n_n >= 1
```

When I copy this code in the Microsoft SQL Management-Studio and exceute it, it shows the expected results. When excecuting it in Java with

```
        s = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
```

it says "Invalid column name 'Indicator'". 
WID and AID are from table1.
de and Indicator are from table 2.
I made a couple of other queries with Java and JDTS which all worked fine. Only the that query with the Join does not work. I think it has something to do with this, but I don't know what.

Anyone has an idea? 
Thanks in advance and best regards.

Edit: Currently I use JTDS 1.2.5, but I also tried 1.3.0 which doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If `Indicator` and `de` are from `Table2` write so in the query. Don't assume it is implied. Also you should write Joins the way they are supposed to be written - using JOIN clause and not in the 'old-style' implicit way.

Also you must add ORDER BY if you are using TOP otherwise you won't know what 15 rows will you get.

Not sure if it will help you, but try (something like) this:

```
SELECT TOP 15 WID,AID,de FROM 
(
    SELECT t1.WID, t1.AID, t2.de, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.WID ASC) AS r_n_n 
    FROM [database].[dbo].[table1] t1
    INNER JOIN [database].[dbo].[table2] t2 ON t1.AID = t2.INDICATOR
) x 
WHERE r_n_n >= 1
ORDER BY r_n_n
```

Comment: Thank for your help! Sadly this does not change anything. Again, when copying the query to the Management-Studio it works perfectly fine and when quering it via the java-code I get this error.

Comment: @JohnJohnson Like I said I was not sure if this will help. It is an improvement and fix on your SQL. At least I think know you can be more sure the problem is somewhere in your Java code or settings. Maybe you should put more of your Java code so someone can check it.

Comment: I found the error. There was a mistake in the code after I received the data. This resulted in using the 'Indicator'-Column at a place where it was not allowed to be used. Thank you for help!